# Uninstall Boost 1.66 with yum

Tags: boost, yum

We have a Linux (CentOS) system with **Boost 1.66**. We need to have **Boost 1.53** installed instead. I think it's wise to  *uninstall Boost 1.66 first* and then install 1.53.

I've found dozens of ways to uninstall Boost with wget, but we don't have wget. We have yum, and yum is largely a mystery to me. Is there a way to uninstall Boost using yum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting. I have a centos 7 system and if I was to install it from the standard repository I would get 1.53.

If you know that boost is not required for any other package then `yum erase boost` is how you do it. Then `yum install boost-1.53`, or something along those lines, assuming it is still available in the repo you are using.

I don't know how you intend to use it, but it is relatively easy to have multiple versions of boost on one system. You can compile it yourself and then install the libraries and include files in directories that are not in the standard path the compiler and loader are looking for. Then you just need to specify these locations when you compile your code.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I got it resolved another way. Thanks for the answer! :)